# MySQL CASE not working for ORDERY BY where two columns are used

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to use the following SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM Data WHERE tid=1 ORDER BY CASE WHEN round=0 THEN date ELSE round, date END ASC
```

but it doesn't work due to the `round, date` bit. Works fine if I make that bit `round` e.g. but not with both.

If `round=0` then I want to be able to sort ascending on `round` first then `date`. Is that possible?

What I'm trying to achieve is a sorted array of rows which is sorted on `round` first then `date` second. But, if `round` is zero then I just want that row to appear inbetween the dates where that record would fit even though it would have a zero `round` value.

Comment: Can you provide examples of what the sorted result would look like?  Your question doesn't make sense, because a given date could be almost anywhere in the results, given that `round` could have any value.

Comment: I actually realised I was over complicating matters and I only really needed to sort by date because, by nature of the rules in which I'm working, the round number order is generally bound to the date order. I did consider deleting the question, but I find the answers useful nonetheless and they may be useful to others, so I won't delete it. Sorry for the confusion @GordonLinoff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could be using a couple of case when one for each column

```
  SELECT * 
  FROM Data 
  WHERE tid=1 
  ORDER BY ( CASE WHEN round= 0  THEN date ELSE round  END) ASC , 
           ( CASE WHEN round= 0  THEN NULL  ELSE date  END) ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

A `case` *expression* returns only one value.  If you want rows with `round = 0` first, then you can do:

```
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN round = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 2 END),
         round, date
```

This can be shortened to:

```
ORDER BY (round = 0) DESC, round, date
```

However, I'm not 100% sure this what you really want.

If `round` only takes on two values then your question would make more sense.  In this case, you really want to sort by `date` first:

```
ORDER BY date, round;
```

However, that is speculation on what the data values look like.